# How to make RLMResults mutable?

Tags: ios, iphone, realm

The Realm doc says the `RLMResults` are lick `NSArray`. I have some results returned from the database and I want to merge it into another `RLMResults`. But it seems it's immutable, How to make a `RLMResults` add objects from another `RLMResults`? or make it mutable? or convert it to `NSArray`?

Comment: Trying to answer your question, and really starting to hate this API design haha. Why do you need to combine the RLMResults?

Comment: @MillieSmith I need to combine RLMResults with RLMResults.

Comment: Can you share more about what you are trying to do? A little code sample would be good. This could be something that we could consider based on the use cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is something you would have to do manually. You could create an RLMArray by concatenating your two results.

We are discussing a union/merge method further down on the roadmap for RLMObjects of the same type though.

Any bit you can share will help us understand the use cases and potentially impact the api design

As long as they are the same type, here's a generic example

```
let currentTask = Task.objectsWhere("name = %@", "First task").firstObject() as Task
let currentRecords = currentTask.records
let arrayOfRecords = RLMArray(objectClassName: "Record")

arrayOfRecords.addObjects(currentRecords)

let futureTask = Task.objectsWhere("name = %@", "Future task").firstObject() as Task
let futureRecords = futureTask.records

arrayOfRecords.addObjects(futureRecords)
```

Comment: Can you provide code to convert an RLMResults object to an RLMArray object? I can't figure out how to do that, and it would essentially be the answer to OP's question. It also seems odd to me that RLMArray can't be instantiated, since you can arbitrarily add objects to an instance. Also, this is a little out of scope of the question, but in RLMResults, what is the use of having firstObject and lastObject? I can't find a way to get other items from those. These are probably naive questions - I'm new to the library.

Comment: No problem, i've edited my example to include this. It can be instantiated with a type. How were you trying to instantiate it?

Not sure what the last question is, but I use firstObject a lot like you see in the above example since Task.objectsWhere... will return an RLMResults, when I'm just looking for a Task. lastObject might be used when you want to know the last Task that was added based on your search criteria

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution from duemunk: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1046

Basically I convert the RLMResults to [RLMObject]:

`func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
    var array = [T]()
    for result in self {
        if let result = result as? T {
            array.append(result)
        }
    }
    return array
}`

`let tracks = Track.allObjects().toArray(Track.self) // tracks is of type [Track]`