# How can i shuffle RLMResults in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Any idea how can i shuffle randomly for `RLMResults`? I couldn't find anyway to do it via `RLMSortDescriptor`.

I tried writing my own swap algorithm, but it's giving me error (cannot assign to results of this expression*).

```
func simpleRandomSwap(rlmobjects:RLMResults!) -> RLMResults! {
    if (rlmobjects != nil && rlmobjects.count > 0) {

        let indexcount = Int(rlmobjects.count)

        for (var i=0 ; i<indexcount; i++) {
            let randomUInt:UInt = UInt(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(indexcount)))
            let myuint = UInt(i)


            // simple swap
            var temp = rlmobjects.objectAtIndex(myuint)
            rlmobjects.objectAtIndex(randomUInt) = rlmobjects.objectAtIndex(myuint)
            rlmobjects.objectAtIndex(myuint) = temp


        } // end for loop

    }


    return rlmobjects
}
```

Comment: I think you have to convert your RLMResults object to NSMutableArray and than shuffling it.

Comment: Is there any more direct method of achieving that? Converting to NSMutableArray would require another for loop, which would incur some unnecessary performance penalty, IMO

Comment: I was thinking the same but issue is i) Unlike NSSortDescriptor, RLMSortDescriptor does't take NSComparator as a parameter so you can not do shuffling while fetching the data. ii) RLMReults will not let you replace its object at runtime.

Comment: In Objective-C, I would convert an RLMResults to NSMutableArray in one line of code using KVC like this [[rlmobjects valueForKey:@"self"].mutableCopy, is something like rlmobjects.valueForKey(“self”) not possible in swift?

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847359/how-to-make-rlmresults-mutable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a quick note: `RLMResults` have no defined order unless they are sorted via `RLMSortDescriptor`.

Instead, to randomly sort you have two options:

1. Add a integer property to your object schema and assign random values to all the objects. You can then use a `RLMSortDescriptor` with `RLMResults` to sort the objects.
2. As mentioned in the comments above, copy the `RLMObjects` into an array and perform a random sort on this.

Here is an extension to `RLMObject` that does this:

```
extension RLMResults {
    public func toShuffledArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {

        var array = [T]()

        for result in self {
            if let result = result as? T {
                array.append(result)
            }
        }

        let count = array.count

        if count > 1 {
            for i in 0..<(count - 1) {
                let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + Int(i)
                swap(&array[i], &array[j])
            }
        }

        return array
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
let shuffled = results.toShuffledArray(TestObject.self)
```

Comment: The problem with putting them in an array is that the collection looses the feature of automatic updates.

Comment: To handle automatic updates, you would then need to add a notification block to the Realm instance that could re-trigger the generation of the shuffled array with the new data.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5:**

You can just use default method:

```
let shuffled = results.shuffled()
```